# How to make flatMap chain for chain of objects?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, flatmap

I have the following class definations.

Insurance.java

```
package Chapter10;

public class Insurance {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Car.java

```
package Chapter10;

import java.util.Optional;

public class Car {

    private Optional<Insurance> insurance;

    public Optional<Insurance> getInsurance() {
        return insurance;
    }

    public void setInsurance(Optional<Insurance> insurance) {
        this.insurance = insurance;
    }
}
```

Person.java

```
package Chapter10;

import java.util.Optional;

public class Person {

    private Optional<Car> car;

    public Optional<Car> getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(Optional<Car> car) {
        this.car = car;
    }
}
```

Now, I have following main class, But I am getting NullPoinerException
for Person p.

```
package Chapter10;

import java.util.Optional;

public class OptionalTester {

    public static String getCarInsuranceName(Optional<Person> person) {
        return person.flatMap(Person::getCar)
                .flatMap(Car::getInsurance)
                .map(Insurance::getName)
                .orElse("Unknown");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Insurance iffco = new Insurance();
        iffco.setName("IFFCO TOKIO");

        Insurance argo = new Insurance();
        argo.setName("HDFC ARGO");

        Car i10 = new Car();
        i10.setInsurance(Optional.of(iffco));

        Car santro = new Car();

        Person p = new Person();
        p.setCar(Optional.of(santro));

        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setCar(Optional.of(i10));

        System.out.println("---------------FROM PERSON GET INSURANCE----------------------");

        Optional<Insurance> optInsurance = Optional.ofNullable(argo);
        Optional<String> name = optInsurance.map(Insurance::getName);


        System.out.println(getCarInsuranceName(Optional.of(p1)));
        System.out.println(getCarInsuranceName(Optional.of(p)));

    }
}
```

I am getting NPE for the line Optional.of(p), I know that p1 has a car and that car has an insurance so that works.

In, case of p the insurance is not present so I get NPE.
But if I do it with Optional.empty(), I correctly get **Unknown** as output.

How do I make it more generalized that if anything is broken I get **Unknown** ?

Comment: Suggestion - Don't use `Optional` as attribute types and method arguments. Just for a sample, even this could solve things `class Car { private Insurance insurance;
        public Optional<Insurance> getInsurance() {
            return Optional.ofNullable(insurance);
        } }`

Comment: I took the example from Java 8 in Action.

Comment: Sorry for being naive, But I kept it attribute types as optional just to signify that those values may not be set in the psvm or anyone using it. 
Any reason why it was not working in first place..

Comment: @Naman Got the difference, In my case the Optional<Insurance> insurance is null and calling map on it gives NPE, In the edit you suggested Car::getInsurance gives Optional.ofNullable(null), that's Optional without anything, Optional.empty, thus map doesn't do anything and orElse is returned

Comment: Indeed...and then imagine using `Optional` attribute evaluating to `null`! What could be worse?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the short answer is "you can't". The reason for this is that `Optional` should be a monad (a higher-order object that allows you to wrap certain operations in a certain container, for short), but in Java, it isn't. Therefore, the `flatMap`s don't chain correctly. For a longer discussion, you might want to see https://www.sitepoint.com/how-optional-breaks-the-monad-laws-and-why-it-matters/

Answer (score 0):

In santro car insurence is null.

import java.util.Optional;

public class OptionalTester {

```
public static String getCarInsuranceName(Optional<Person> person) {
    return person.flatMap(Person::getCar)
            .flatMap(Car::getInsurance)
            .map(Insurance::getName)
            .orElse("Unknown");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Insurance iffco = new Insurance();
    iffco.setName("IFFCO TOKIO");

    Insurance argo = new Insurance();
    argo.setName("HDFC ARGO");

    Car i10 = new Car();
    i10.setInsurance(Optional.of(iffco));

    Car santro = new Car();
    santro.setInsurance(Optional.of(argo)); \\ Insurence was null.

    Person p = new Person();
    p.setCar(Optional.of(santro));

    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.setCar(Optional.of(i10));

    System.out.println("---------------FROM PERSON GET INSURANCE----------------------");

    Optional<Insurance> optInsurance = Optional.ofNullable(argo);
    Optional<String> name = optInsurance.map(Insurance::getName);


    System.out.println(getCarInsuranceName(Optional.of(p1)));
    System.out.println(getCarInsuranceName(Optional.of(p)));

}
```

}

Comment: You got it wrong, see the comments of the answer to get why one thing works and other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Car should work.

public class Car {

```
    private Insurance insurance;

    public Optional<Insurance> getInsurance() {
       return Optional.ofNullable(insurance);
    }

    public void setInsurance(Optional<Insurance> insurance) {
        this.insurance = insurance.orElse(null);
    }
}
```